# NHibernate Query cache bug with hyphens

Tags: nhibernate, caching, query-cache

I am using NH 3.3.1.4000 with Oracle 10g and SQL Server 2008.

I ran into this possible bug recently. Consider the following two queries:

```
var query1 = session.Query<Content>().Cacheable()
                    .Where(c => c.Name == "test-test").ToList();

var query2 = session.CreateQuery("from Content c where c.Name = :name")
                    .SetString("name", "test-test")
                    .SetCacheable(true); 
var list = query.List<Content>();
```

Either one of the above queries will produce the following SQL query:

```
select content0_.Id       as Id6_,      
content0_.Name   as Name6_,      
from   Content content0_
where  content0_.Name = ''
```

Any parameter that is passed in and has a '-' (hyphen), doesn't not make it to the actual SQL query

If I remove the .Cacheable or SetCacheable() or the "-" in the parameter, it works correctly.
Any ideas for workaround before I start looking in to the NH source code?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I can confirm that the same issue exists for SQL Server also. I am guessing it has nothing to do with the database rather with the query cache.
I should have mentioned that the first time the query runs, before caching takes place, the query that is generated is correct. But when I run the same query the second time, this time loading from query cache, cacheable with hyphens doesn't work. Please see the following test I ran using SQL Server 2008 on a .Net MVC app.

```
var test1 = session.Query<Student>().Cacheable().Where(c => c.Firstname == "first-name").ToList();

var test2 = session.Query<Student>().Where(c => c.Firstname == "first-name").ToList();

var test3 = session.Query<Student>().Cacheable().Where(c => c.Firstname == "firstname").ToList();
```

The first time I loaded the page the following queries were generated and were all correct:

```
-- statement #1
select student0_.Id        as Id1_,
   student0_.Firstname as Firstname1_,
   student0_.Lastname  as Lastname1_
from   Students student0_
where  student0_.Firstname = 'first-name'

-- statement #2
select student0_.Id        as Id1_,
   student0_.Firstname as Firstname1_,
   student0_.Lastname  as Lastname1_
from   Students student0_
where  student0_.Firstname = 'first-name'

-- statement #3
select student0_.Id        as Id1_,
   student0_.Firstname as Firstname1_,
   student0_.Lastname  as Lastname1_
from   Students student0_
where  student0_.Firstname = 'firstname'
```

But after I reload the page, and let Query Cache do its thing, I get the following three queries:

```
-- statement #1
Cached query: 
select student0_.Id        as Id1_,
   student0_.Firstname as Firstname1_,
   student0_.Lastname  as Lastname1_
from   Students student0_
where  student0_.Firstname = ''

-- statement #2
select student0_.Id        as Id1_,
   student0_.Firstname as Firstname1_,
   student0_.Lastname  as Lastname1_
from   Students student0_
where  student0_.Firstname = 'first-name'

-- statement #3
Cached query: 
select student0_.Id        as Id1_,
   student0_.Firstname as Firstname1_,
   student0_.Lastname  as Lastname1_
from   Students student0_
where  student0_.Firstname = 'firstname'
```

As you can see, the parameter is empty in statement #1 the second time. The only difference between statement #1 and statement #2 is the use of query cache. Cached query works fine in the second load (test3) as long as there is no "-" hyphen in the parameter.

Comment: Both queries generate correct results on SQL Server (I don't have an Oracle handy). Are you really sure those are the values you're passing? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The issue exists even if the database is SQL Server. When you load data the first time, it works fine, but the second time you load the data (from query cache) the issue is evident. Please see my update above with the actual queries.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you are caching, the second time there's no query at all.

Comment: I realize that that there is no database query being sent in the second call, and it is not related to the database at all. It has to do with the query cache. The data that NHibernate is loading from cache is incorrect if there is hyphen in the query. How would you account for the difference between statement #1 and statement #3? The query cache has '' empty string in one case and 'fistname' in the other. You can try it for yourself.

Comment: BTW, I am using NHProfiler to see what's going on.

Comment: Any ideas yet anyone? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this must be a bug in [NHibernate Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/NHProf) rather than with NHibernate or the query cache. I have been able to reproduce your problem with parameters including hyphens for cached queries being displayed as empty strings in the profiler.

I have always gotten correct result sets in my tests, though. Enabling debug level for logger `NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache` also indicates that the query cache never sees these empty string parameters, but rather the actual parameter values with hyphens.

My conclusion is that the profiler displays these parameters incorrectly when listing a cached query.